# Scooter Speedo Drive Repair

Tags: motorcycle, scooter, peugeot, speedometer, material

The speedo drive housing has sheared at some point on my 125cc Peugeot scooter, and no longer has anything from stopping it spinning 360 degrees apart from friction. It doesn't spin freely when I ride but goes round half a turn eventually and means the speedo cable is too tight to work.

I'm not great at materials so can't decide the best path of repair to save having a new part. I like to repair rather than replace whenever I can!

[image: sheared part image]

I'm not great with materials so can't tell what it's made of, but it seems to have a speckled texture inside. What's going to be the best attempt at repairing this, I can stick weld but will it just melt it? Or screw something into it? All it needs is about 5-10mm material readded and it will sit exactly as it used to when turned to the correct position.